# When do we need const and & in RcppEigen programming

Tags: rcpp

In practice I use R a lot. Sometimes, I need to speed up the R programming, so I choose use R with Rcpp and RcppEigen. I am new to RcppEigen, so I first collect some examples from Internet. What confuses me quite a lot is I don't know when should I add `const` and `&` in input parameter area. My little example is as follows, which can be tested successfully in R on Win10

```
// Ref: rcppeigen_hello_world.cpp in library(RcppEigen)

// we only include RcppEigen.h which pulls Rcpp.h in for us
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// via the depends attribute we tell Rcpp to create hooks for
// RcppEigen so that the build process will know what to do
//
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]


using namespace Eigen; // e.g.: Eigen::MatrixXd, etc.


//[[Rcpp::export]]
double sign1(double &x){
    if(x>0){
        return 1.0;
    }else if(x<0){
        return -1.0;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
int sign2(const double& x) {
    return (x > 0) - (x < 0);
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
double trc(MatrixXd X, MatrixXd Y) {
return (X.adjoint() * Y).trace();   
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
MatrixXd outp(const VectorXd & x) {
MatrixXd m = x * x.transpose();
return m;
}


/*** R
### 
x = -2
sign(x)
sign1(x)
sign2(x)

###
x = matrix(replicate(9,1), ncol=3, nrow=3)
y = matrix(1:9,3,3)
sum(diag(crossprod(x,y)))
psych::tr(crossprod(x,y))
trc(x,y)

###
z = 1:3
z %*% t(z)
tcrossprod(z)
outp(z)
*/
```

Comment: As you show, one doesn't "need" anything: both compile. Underneath is an older C "union" data structure called `SEXP` that _is always a pointer_ so "const correctness" is a little tricky.  That has been discussed a few times in context of Rcpp and RcppArmadillo too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  Tks Dirk!  As you said, I hereafter choose not to use `const` and `&` with Rcpp and RcppEigen for simplicity and convenience,  focusing on the methodologies and algorithms. @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: Yes, it is a little inelegant from a pure C++ point of view but reflects the C nature. It can be overcome as the RcppArmadillo project does. But it is extra work, and nobody has done it here.